# Perturbation Theory: Approximation of an inverse of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, perturbation-theory

Does someone know theorems about approximating the **inverse of a matrix** through **perturbation theory**? I would be very grateful, if you could recommend me some literature on that.

Because I am reading a paper which says that given a matrix A which is quadratic, real-valued and consists of eigenvectors from another matrix B, then the following **approximation** holds for A because of perturbation theory techniques (and unfortunately they don't say in detail which techniques):

$A^{-1}=(I+H)^{(−1)} \approx (I-H) $, where I is the identity matrix. 
The equality is okay (I calculated it) but I don't understand why the **approximation** holds.

Comment: What do you mean by "$A$ is quadratic"?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I meant that A is a square matrix

Comment: Yes, I had got it. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is just Taylor expansion: 
$$\tag{1}(I+\epsilon K)^{-1} = 1-\epsilon K + O(\epsilon^2), $$ 
so if $H:=\epsilon K$ is small with respect to the identity matrix then you can neglect the quadratic term in the expansion. The proof of (1) is based on Neumann's sums: 
$$ 
(I+\epsilon K)^{-1}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\epsilon^n K^n, $$ 
for all $0\le |\epsilon|<|\lambda|^{-1}$, where $\lambda $ is the dominant eigenvalue of $K$, that is, the eigenvalue that is biggest in modulus. The expansion (1) is just the Neumann sum truncated to the first two summands.

Comment: thank you, I was also told that this is a taylor expansion but applying the taylor expansion onto a matrix is very new to me. I calculated the Neuman's sums and got (1) but what is it's relation to the taylor expansion? @Giuseppe Negro

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: Would you please help me further? I got it that (1) is to be proven with the Neumann sum but I can't see the Taylor expansion (with all the derivatives etc.) in (1) or do you mean that in such cases with matrices Taylor expansion equals the Neumann sum?

Comment: That's just a function of a single variable, $\epsilon$. The Neumann sums contain its complete Taylor expansion.

Comment: I just came across the book "Differential equations: a dynamical systems approach" by Hubbard and West. It contains a short and nice appendix on asymptotic development. Might be a good read for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, for your help and the book recommendation:)

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer was useful, please upvote it. If you think that this answer completely solves the question, please accept it.